# 3D C++ Arbitrary Mesh Triangulation Library?

Tags: c++, 3d, open-source, triangulation

I'm looking for a C++ library to triangulate arbitrary 3D meshes. Preferably open-source but at the very least free for commercial use (so [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) is pretty much out of the question).

I looked at [GTS](http://gts.sourceforge.net/index.html), but it's written in C (is C compatible with C++?), it's old, and the binaries are for Debian platforms (I need Windows binaries or source that can be compiled in VC++ 2008).

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Additionally:**

If it's possible to use a 2D polygon triangulation library such as [polypartition](https://code.google.com/p/polypartition/) or [poly2tri](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) by triangulating each face separately, I can guarantee every face stays on its own plane (every face is flat and all the vertices are on the same plane) and has no holes. I'm not sure how I would go about translating the 3D rotation of the face to 2D space; I assume you would need to use the face's normals. I'm also not sure whether the generated 2D vertices could easily be merged back into the 3D mesh if you were to triangulate each face separately.

Comment: You need to work on your definition of open-source (CGAL is a mix of LGPL and GPL), you probably want a license without copyleft. Yes, C is compatible.

Comment: I stated that it could be open-source or _at the very least free for commercial use_. I would have thought that meant it could be open-source or just binaries but must be free for commercial use. And CGAL is not (as far as I can see) free for commercial use.

Also, what is copyleft? Are you just being humorous or is it different to copyright?

Comment: Ah, a quick Google told me what copyleft is. Funny, never heard of it before. Yes, I want a license without copyleft.

Comment: I understand that CGAL is free for commercial use, as soon as you provide the source code of your software.

Comment: I suppose that you solved your problem now, but it is not hard to convert the 2D coordinates of your vertices on the face (plane defined by a point and a normal) into 3D coordinates, and from 3D to 2D.

Comment: @arthur.sw Well yeah, but providing the source code of my software defeats the point of "commercial".

Comment: @arthur.sw Just commenting to make sure you get a notification. My last comment was from my phone and SE didn't seem to detect your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out myself. Turns out the library that generated the mesh that needed triangulating, [Carve](http://carve-csg.com/), isn't necessarily free for commercial use, so I had to find an alternative. I found [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) (I didn't realise it had these kinds of functions), which has the perfect license for me, is free, of high quality, and seems to have the functions I need. So...hooray!

Answer (score -1):

Check out [umeshu](https://github.com/vladimir-ch/umeshu/).
It's under the MIT license.

Comment: Thanks, but not what I need. It's 2D. I need 3D triangulation. But thanks anyway :)